# Unnable to connect to Redis from inside Docker container

Tags: python, macos, docker, redis

When I start Docker container I get

```
OSError: Multiple exceptions: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('::1', 6379), [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 6379)
```

from Python, but this code works fine on the host machine. How to fix this?

Dockerfile: [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/302350e58ceb9e859d626d0728ddf287), OS: macOS 10.12

Comment: You use multiple CMD statements in your Dockerfile. Only the last one "wins", so `redis-server` isn't started. Please consider splitting the Dockerfile into two separate ones or replace the `redis-server` with an [offical image](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/redis/).

Comment: This article explains several options how to connect different containers via network: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/

Comment: @gesellix I cannot split file and I cannot use the official image. Maybe there is a way to run redis-server and python script in one Dockerfile?

Comment: Why can't you split the Dockerfile? In case you really want to have both in a single container you'll need a tool like `supervisord`. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/

Comment: @gesellix It will be running on a remote server (I am participating in some online competition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have a single `CMD` statement. To start both `redis-server` and `python` inside a single container you'll need to define a script or run a tool like `supervisord` to manage your processes. https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/ explains some options and also gives examples. In your case I would give the approach with a shell script a try. The Phusion base image https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker is a more advanced alternative, starting each process via init service, but might be overkill for your use case.